# How to stretch n times the content of a column, according to another column's length (using awk)?

Tags: awk, sed, command-line

for parsing purpose I need to stretch the content of the first column n times according to the number of characters of another column, within command line.

**Note:** Col2 contains mixed types: <>,.[A-Za-z]

I should turn something like this:

```
cat myFile.tsv 

Col1    Col2
Text1    XXXX
Text2    XX
Text3    XXX
```

Into this:

```
cat myNewFile.tsv 

Col1
Text1    
Text1    
Text1    
Text1    
Text2    
Text2 
Text3    
Text3    
Text3
```

Do you have any efficient suggestions?
Thank you :D !!

Comment: use a for loop... you can use `length` function to get number of characters

Comment: I couldn't handle it with a for loop because of memory limit apparently, is it possible?

Comment: change your given sample into something resembling your actual usecase, unless those `X` are enough to represent it.. and I meant loop using awk, not shell in case you tried it like that.. add the command you tried as well, since it is expected that you show your efforts..

Comment: Ok, i'll try a awk loop. Those X just represent the number of characters in the 2nd column (4,2,3)

Comment: Take a look at `length($2)`.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I think I managed to do it with `awk '{for(i=0;i<length($2);i++)print $1}' myFile.tsv > myNewFile.tsv `

Answer (score 4):

With awk:

```
awk 'NR==1{print $1; next} {for(i=1; i<=length($2); i++){print $1}}' file
```

> `NR` is current row number.

Output:

```
Col1
Text1
Text1
Text1
Text1
Text2
Text2
Text3
Text3
Text3
```

Comment: Sheeze - dead ringer. Wrote a 1-line and looked at your answer and the only difference was the additional `{..}` you have and looping `i=0; i<length($2); i++` and the use of `FNR` instead of `NR`. I like it.

Comment: @cast although not required here, use `-F'\t'` when dealing with tab separated files